# Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

Tags: powershell

**I am getting this error while I am trying to work in PowerShell in my new PC**:
Get-Date : The 'Get-Date' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-Date
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Date:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
  ```

Comment: Can you run `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` and then try.

Comment: Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: I tried this but giving above error.

Comment: Can you use this instead? `[System.DateTime]::Now`

Comment: Check the list of paths specified in your `PSModulePath` environment variable, and make sure that the list contains the directory path where your `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` module is located.

Comment: Yes Path is correct, but no help!

Comment: The right side of the powershell console which displays commands and modules are just empty and nothings helps, pls give a solution anybody??